# adding noWrap to Theme

Tags: themes, typography, nowrap

Im having a syntax problem (sorry... newbie...)   How do I add noWrap to this theme?  I want noWrap (with the elipsis) for every type of text, so the theme seems to be the right place.  I assume within the Typography.  I can always exclude it as needed.
I've tried a few options with no luck

```
const theme = () => createTheme
    ({
    palette: {
        primary: purple,
        secondary: green,
        background: {paper: "green"},
    },

    typography: {
        allVariants: {color: "orange"},
        h1: {fontSize: 100, fontWeight: "bold"  },
        body1: {color: "lime"},
    }
    })
```